# Is there a way to use 2 different graphics cards, with an SLI? If so how?

Tags: graphics-card, desktop-computer, nvidia-geforce

So i'm planning on buying this new PC with a GTX 1050, thing is i bought a GTX 950 last year for my old PC and don't want it to go to waste. So i'm wondering weather i can combine my GTX 950 and GTX 1050 with an SLI for higher game performance.

Comment: Yes, SLI requires similar/identical cards and a 1050 and 950 are not similar enough

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. The GTX 1050 is unable to support SLI.

The GTX 1070 and 1080 support SLI but the GTX 1050 and 1060 do not.

Even if they were able to support SLI the card has to be the same model. You can mix and match manufactures but cannot mix and match model numbers.